# Access Postgres database container but get error

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers

I use docker to run a Postgres database container. My command to start it is:

```
docker run --name postgres-me -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d -p 5432:5432 postgres:alpine
```

Then it is up and running:

```
~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b662971d9b54        postgres:alpine     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres-me
```

Then I try to access the container by:

```
~ $ docker exec -it b662971d9b54 bin/bash
bash-5.0# psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

As you can see above, after I go into the container, then I tried command `psql`, but I got error `could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide username as well.
Try this :
`psql -U <username>`

Comment: What username should I use?

Comment: You can get the username via this command : docker inspect <postgres-container-id> --format '{{.Config.User}}'.